# Why does imageview of image is being cut? (During the Animation, imageview was half outside of the screen)

Tags: android, imageview, animator

[image]

This is what happens when I make animation in an activity.

My ImageView is Dynamically outside of the screen.

But whenever I tried the TranslateAnimation or Animator, the Image is cutoff and showing white blank.

So I've tried the advice the link below

for adding onDraw() After finishing the animation. But the result was the same.

Is there any idea? Or Am I missing something?

Addition: the Clipchildren was also not working.
           There is a restriction that I can't use XML. Because of the dynamic allocation of images not in Resource.

Comment: try this. imageView.animate().translationX(newTranslationX).translationY(newTranslationY).setDuration(duration).start();

Comment: @S T Thanks, I tried that but the image View is still the same.

Comment: clipChildren="false" to `ALL parents of ImageView` is not working?

Comment: @S T oh no It was My fault the View of the Object Animator Must target the imageView. Not a Framelayout. Thanks alot it reaallly did help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@S T 
Comment has an Answer. It really did help.

When you try to Animate the ObjectAnimator.

Please concentrate **what is a Target for animation**.
Is it a layout or ImageView, if it is layout the view will be cut off.
But when it is a imageview The Image view will animate.

Again Thanks to @S T. The problem has solved!